# Snackbar textview returns null in library module

Tags: android, textview, snackbar

I am using design support library's snackbar in my project to display a message since the message is large it is getting truncated after 2 lines. When I tried to change the maxlines by snackbar textview using the following code ,it returns null. Snackbar is in a library module,that I have in my project.

```
View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
TextView textView = (TextView)snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setMaxLines(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had the same issue.
I have a maven repo, with LOTS of utils.
And one method "getConfiguredSnackBar" changes the color of the snackbar text to white, because some themes can change it to black, making it hard to read.

It works ok using your aproach (if it's in the same module). But when in a library, the findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text) is null.

My ugly, but working, approach:

```
    @Nullable
private static TextView findTextViewInSnackbar(Snackbar snackbar){
    ViewGroup snackView = ((ViewGroup) snackbar.getView());
    for (int i = 0; i < snackView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = snackView.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof TextView) {
            return ((TextView) child);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It work's fine. If, for some reason, you have more than one TextView, well... Good luck. Modify this and do as you wish.